# Trim specific string with leading zeros

Tags: sql, oracle, trim

I am operating on an oracle server with a table that contains one really weird column.
This column contains strings like:

- [0X]+00000026
- [22]+2222,555,6666
- [WRI] 0000,00
- FKI
- 555

Every case has its own structure.
Now I would like to transform the first example to '26'.
The second one I would like to transform to '2222'.
The last one to '555'.

How would you build that?
Have you ever seen something similar?

Best Regards

Comment: "I would like to" is useless. *Why* would you want to do that? What **rules** lead from input to output?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. You are right! In the first example everything with brackets should be removed as well es the '+'. The all leading zeros should be removed.

Comment: OK, that's the first example. Why don't you want anything from the 3rd? There are no brackets nor + in the 5th example, yet you want to return 555. What pattern do you follow?

Comment: I need for ever type a different pattern, as you mentioned.

Comment: If it is as you commented, then you have to write a new *expression* for every case as you can't fit them under any known set of rules that lead from *input* to *output*.

Comment: And how would you build that sql? I mean, lets take 2 cases. The first one is about to remove the bracket and '+' and all leading numbers ([0X]). The second case will take the original string ('FKI', '555')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this does what you want:

```
select replace(regexp_substr(str, '(^|[+])[0-9]+'), '+', '')
```

Here is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have a second column that shows me the status like '1B' or '00'. How can I add your approach just for rows where status like '00'?

Comment: @joshua . . . If `status = '00'` doesn't work, then you should ask a new question.